# How would I use MapKit to drop pin on a store with Zipcode / Postode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

If the only information I have for a particular store or business (or restaurant etc) is its Name, Postcode (or Zipcode) and Country, how would I create an MKMapView which locates the store and drops a pin on the location?
So kind of replicating if I typed in "Pizza Paradiso, WC1E 7BS, UK", except without the info bubble (but with pin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called geocoding and the MapKit currently only does **reverse**-geocoding (from lat/long to address) using the MKReverseGeocoder class.

To do geocoding, you'll have to use some other api like the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and then take the latitude and longitude it gives you to create a region which you pass to the map view's `setRegion:animated:` method.

To drop a pin, you would take the resulting lat/long and create an annotation object and add it to the map view using addAnnotation.

Comment: Thanks, I found this useful for Google's API: http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/